# Why does box-sizing not apply here?

Tags: css, width, padding, box-sizing

I have a table cell with box-sizing: border-box, which means that when I specify width: 100px it INCLUDES any borders. I have this cell with a set width of 16px and border-box. Still, the element renders as 26px wide. 
https://i.gyazo.com/e35d849169ecfa59ba2f548e28033c52.png

What am I missing/overlooking?

Comment: Share full code, we don't trust screenshots ..

Comment: wdym by "we don't trust screenshots". The whole code itself is kinda not public

Comment: it's html/css code which is a client side technologie and meant to be public to everywhere unless you are developing a website only for you. If you cannot share your code, we cannot help you

Answer (score -1):

That might not work for your case, but try adding `display: block;` on a table cell.

Comment: None of those I tried. display: none  didn't help, sadly

Comment: What were you expecting from ‘display:none’? Why don’t you share code; I’ll try to help you.

Comment: As you suggested trying display: block I quickly used Chrome's autocomplete to test all possible values. My first answer could have been misleading since I meant "not a single one" with "none", not the actual display: none option. display: none woudln't have done anything, of course.